# You will find it hard to believe, but I have decided to move into the country. What is the it's mean?

Tags: word-usage

> You will find **it** hard to believe, but I have decided to move into the country.

What is the *it*'s mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pronoun *it* refers, in this case, to the whole statement that follows the *but*. It means the same, essentially, to say "you will find it hard to believe that I have decided to move to the country, or "you will find this hard to believe: I have decided to move to the country". English usually has a lot of ways to say one thing.

They do have different nuance, though. The *but* version is emphasising that it is true despite the fact that other people will find it hard to believe. The *that* version is emphasising the prediction that they will find it hard to believe. The *this* and colon version is stilted and formal, but it will be used sometimes.

The *that* and *this* versions also hold some special rhetorical value because it can be claimed that they are not actually asserting that the speaker has decided to move to the country, but just commenting on whether people would believe it. That's for playing games with, though. If you wanted to indicate that people would not believe it without implying that it is true, it would be better to say "you would not believe me, if I told you had decided to move to the country". That leaves the possible implication that such a decision has been made, but it is very weak and people will generally check, rather than assuming.

Comment: **The that and this versions also hold some special rhetorical value because it can be claimed that they are not actually asserting that the speaker has decided to move to the country, but just commenting on whether people would believe it.** Why? It just said that **I have decided to move to the country**. How can I think he/she will not do?

Answer (score 2):

We use the expression **You will find it hard to believe** when we tell people something that we think will come as a surprise to them.

The expression **to move into the country** means to move (from an urban residence) to a rural home.

It's common for people who live in cities and towns to move away from their places of work when they retire in order to enjoy a more peaceful life in hamlets or isolated dwellings in the countryside - that's to say, in rural areas. Of course, people may move to the countryside for many other reasons as well.

The expression does not mean emigrating - moving to a different country.

So the speaker is informing somebody that he/she has decided to move from a residence in an urban area to one in a rural area.

Comment: Why he doesn't say ' You will find it hard to believe that I have decided to move into the country'.  And the but in the original sentence is weird, I think.

Comment: @Y.zeng The speaker could use **that** but has chosen to use **but** in order to better contrast the first half of the statement with the second half.  This is a common construction in English.

Comment: Thanks. I am a Chinese, but you told me so much which I did know.